# Access EJB from different WAR in JBoss AS via injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, cdi, ejb-3.1

My Project structure is as follows

JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final-redhat-4

A war VWeb.war which contains an EJB , when VWeb is deployed I get the following

```
 java:global/VWeb/QServiceImpl!com.vi.qciapi.QService
java:app/VWeb/QServiceImpl!com.vi.qciapi.QService
java:module/QServiceImpl!com.vi.qciapi.QService
java:global/VWeb/QServiceImpl
java:app/VWeb/QServiceImpl
java:module/QServiceImpl
```

I have got another war (ControlWeb-portlet.war) which is a liferay project and I am trying to access the above EJB within a bean from ControlWeb-portlet . The bean is @ViewScoped This has been done based on a link found [here](http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2010/01/06/porting-the-viewscoped-jsf-annotation-to-cdi)

I have tried all these combinations but nothing seems to work

```
@Inject
QService qService;

@EJB
QService qService;

@EJB(mappedName="java:global/VWeb/QServiceImpl!com.vi.qciapi.QService")
QService qService;

@EJB(beanInterface=QService.class)
QService qService;

@EJB(mappedName="java:global/VWeb/QServiceImpl!com.vi.qciapi.QService")
QService qService;
```

I kept an EJB in the same project ControlWeb-portlet which is deployed as follows

```
java:global/ControlWeb-portlet/CdiServiceImpl!com.clink.cdi.CdiServiceImpl
    java:app/ControlWeb-portlet/CdiServiceImpl!com.clink.cdi.CdiServiceImpl
    java:module/CdiServiceImpl!com.clink.cdi.CdiServiceImpl
    java:global/ControlWeb-portlet/CdiServiceImpl
    java:app/ControlWeb-portlet/CdiServiceImpl
    java:module/CdiServiceImpl
```

and I am able to inject the EJB with

```
@EJB
CdiServiceImpl cdiServiceImpl;
```

Is there anything specific that I have to while accessing an EJB from a different WAR

Thanks in advance

Charlie

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I answered this question on the [JBoss forums](https://developer.jboss.org/message/817451#817451) a while ago. Since it was marked as the correct answer there, I thought I'd reproduce it here as well.

---

I got it to work using the following approach:

First, define EJBs as resources using the `@Produces` annotation:

```
public class Resources {
          @Produces
          @EJB(lookup = "java:global/.../WhateverService")
          private WhateverService whateverService;
}
```

Then, inject the EJB resources in your bean using the `@Inject` annotation:

```
// ...
@Inject
private WhateverService whateverService;
// ...
```

Works like a charm. I'm also using a similar CDI view scope approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should keep using @EJB for a remote bean.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix is to add a dependency to `VWeb.war` into the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`file in the second war. Which would look like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="deployment.VWeb.war" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If that doesn't work you could also try a workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060314).
(Create a `@Stateless` EJB in `ControlWeb-portlet.war` which injects the required bean via `@EJB` and then exposes this via producer methods, which allow you to use `@Inject`in the final destination.)